# What is this purple mushroom growing in my pot?

Tags: containers, mushrooms

I found these purple mushrooms growing in one of my pots. I've been removing them and throwing them away.

I have no idea what to google to identify them.

Mostly I want to know if this will harm the plant.

[image: Purple mushroom]

Comment: Use sterilized potting soil (for cactus and succulents).  Just one live spore floating in the air or using  garden soil from out of doors might explain the mushrooms.

Answer (score 3):

The mushrooms you see are the fruiting body of a mycelial network which is growing in the potting mix of your plant.  So, if you want to get rid of it, then you'll need to repot the plant in new potting mix.

Identification of mushrooms is [fraught with issues](https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/28/16054834/mushroom-identifying-app-machine-vision-ai-dangerous), and best done using a [spore print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spore_print).

Comment: Ok, so lets say I can't identify reliably, how should I proceed?

Comment: Unles ssomeone identifies it here, I'd suggest asking on https://www.shroomery.org/ which is a dedicated mushroom forum.  Who knows, it might turn out to be a psilocybin!

Comment: @GrahamChiu is the mushroom known to be dangerous in any way?

Comment: @Ljk2000 only if you eat poisonous mushrooms.

Comment: ”Mostly I want to know if this will harm the plant.” - this part is not covered in your answer?

Comment: @Stephie without an identification one can't answer that.

Comment: How about “unlikely to harm the plant unless growing out of the trunk or roots, but often means the soil is constantlu humid”?

Comment: It may even be synergistic, who knows without an ID?